# not found HTML in JavaFX to Android

Tags: android, javafx

I tried with this code in JavaFX:

```
    @FXML
    private WebView contenedorWeb;

    URL urlGoogleMaps = getClass().getResource("MapaHtml.html");
    webengine=contenedorWeb.getEngine();
    webengine.load(urlGoogleMaps.toExternalForm());
```

in JavaFX work fine, but when I run in Android with this metod: https://bitbucket.org/javafxports/android/wiki/Building%20and%20deploying%20JavaFX%20Applications

in the telephone the html file can´t found, appears the warning:

```
    Web page not available

    The Web page at jar:file:/data/data/com.hello/app_dex/Application_resources.jar!/controller/MapaHtml.html might be temporarily down or it may have moved permanently to a new wed address
```

(com.hello is the package (-PPACKAGE))

any idea??

Regards

Comment: I doubt the current JavaFX -> Android port supports the JavaFX WebView, you could confirm this on the relevant [JavaFX port support forum](http://javafxports.org/page/Support).

Comment: I read in forums that JavaFX Webview not work in android, but if I put a URL instead of a HTML file, work fine! thus if find the HTML file it should work fine too..?

Answer (score 0):

I've faced the same problem and after one day of trying I've finally found the solution.
I don't know, why it's not working the same in Android and normal JavaFX, but following workaround saved my day.

```
        File file = null;
        String resource = "/pl/dur/client/Map.html";
        URL res = getClass().getResource(resource);
        if (res.toString().startsWith("jar:")) {
            try {
                InputStream input = getClass().getResourceAsStream(resource);
                file = new File("/data/data/pl.dur.client/app_dex/Map.html");
                file.createNewFile();
                OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(file);
                int read;
                byte[] bytes = new byte[1024];

                while ((read = input.read(bytes)) != -1) {
                    out.write(bytes, 0, read);
                }
            } 
            catch (IOException ex) {
                log.error(ex.getStackTrace());
            }
        }
        webEngine.load("file://" + file.getAbsolutePath());
        webEngine.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        getChildren().add(webView);
```

Very important is this path **/data/data/pl.dur.client/app_dex** which is data path of Your application. I'm creating copy of HTML file in application data directory and this file is passed to WebView. 
Hope this will help.